# Ruby- Help converting 4 digit year input into 2 digit output

Tags: ruby

So far I have.

```
puts "Enter year:"
year = gets.chomp.to_i
res = year %2 100
puts "Welcome to '#{year}"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's that `2` after `%`?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at other answers for questions that were kinda similar and it seems that doing %02 would have taken it down to the last two spaces, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can we assume you want to convert for example `2022` to `22` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I want to convert input of year(2022 etc.) to (22 etc.)

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry. I'm new to here and programming. I'll try to do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll have to update your code sample a little bit, try this:

```
 puts "Enter year:"
 year = gets.chomp.to_i  # 4 digits year like 2022
 res = year % 100 # 2 digits year like 22
 puts "Welcome to '#{res}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up 2 things:

1. Getting the "last part" (modulo 100) of the year: `year % 100`, where `%` is the modulo operator.
2. And printing out a value with 2 digits using leading zeros: `"%02d" % value`, where `%` is a different operator, separating the template string and its arguments.

You should combine these things:

```rb
year = 2002
res = "%02d" % (year % 100)
puts res
# 02
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out most of the issues with your specific code, so I won't do that.  I did however want to suggest that you shouldn't even need to convert to `integer` or use `modulo`.  You should be able to simply use the string and take the last 2 characters:

```
year = gets.chomp
puts "Welcome to '#{year[-2..-1]}"
#=>  Welcome to '22
```

Comment: As of ruby 2.6 you can use an endless range `-2..` rather than `-2..-1`